# Web parts are having theme issues?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, communication-site

The company I work for has a SharePoint Online communication page. We have different departments sites such as HR, Marketing, IT, Business Development, etc.

We have this blue theme background set for all our sites:

[image]

Let's say our HR site, we have a few web parts (Library) and when we click on it our current theme is applied.

[image]

However, we have this issue in some of our other sites like IT and Business Development that when you click on some web part we have a blue background:

[image]
This is Our Business Development page when I click on the Business Development News web part I got the blue background issue below:

[image]

[image]

Any ideas, why the current theme is not being applied properly to some web parts. We had checked the composed look settings of each site and everything is configured the same way as the HR page. We have some custom CSS that we created for each site. We checked the HR site master pages, the custom CSS link is being called in, the same way in our IT and Business Development sites.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce your problem in my environment.

I recommend you manually change it to the color you want.

Detailed code reference to the following article:

https://collab365.community/sharepoint-online-css-tips/

If you still have doubts about this issue, I recommend your create service requests to contact Office 365 support.

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/praveenkumar/2013/07/17/how-to-create-service-requests-to-contact-office-365-support/